# Close PrimeFaces dialog after OmniFaces sendFile

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm trying to create a `<p:ajaxstatus />` like indicator when downloading a file using OmniFaces `Faces.sendFile` function. When the user clicks the Export link a dialog tells them the file is being created (because this can take sometime depending on the data size), then after the file downloads the message closes.

In my xhtml:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="excelDialog" modal="true">
    <h2>Building Spreadsheet</h2>
</p:dialog>

<h:commandLink value="Export" action="#{resultsBean.excelExport}" onclick="excelDialog.show();" />
```

and in my ViewScoped bean:

```
public void excelExport() throws IOException {
    ExcelExport ee = new ExcelExport(results);
    Faces.sendFile(ee.getFile(), true);
}
```

What I can't figure is how I could close the dialog after the response is complete.

I've tried using the PrimeFaces RequestContext (which should work for non-ajax requests) but does not work.  I wonder if this is because `Faces.sendFile` calls `FacesContext.responseComplete()` before the RequestContext is used.

```
public void excelExport() throws IOException {
    ExcelExport ee = new ExcelExport(results);
    Faces.sendFile(ee.getFile(), true);
    RequestContext c = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();        
    c.execute("PF('excelDialog').hide();");       
}
```

- JSF 2.1
- PrimeFaces 4.0
- OmniFaces 1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I wonder if this is because `Faces.sendFile` calls `FacesContext.responseComplete()` before the RequestContext is used.*

It just prevents the download file content from being corrupted because something else's trying to write more data to the response.

You're basically trying to send multiple responses on a single request. This is not possible. You can send only one response back per request. If your attempt were possible, the download file content would be corrupted because some XML code representing a PrimeFaces ajax response would be appended to the end of the download file content.

You basically need to send 2 requests whereby the 2nd request is fired automatically on end of 1st request. The 1st request should prepare the file and park it somewhere (property of `@ViewScoped` bean?) and then close the dialog and trigger the 2nd request. The 2nd request should just download the parked file. The 1st request can be done by ajax like with `<p:commandButton>`, but the 2nd request must be fully synchronous for obvious reasons. You can perform the 2nd request using a `<h:commandLink>` which is hidden using CSS.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:commandLink value="Export" action="#{resultsBean.excelExport}" 
        onclick="excelDialog.show();" 
        oncomplete="excelDialog.hide(); document.getElementById('formId:linkId').click();" />
    <h:commandLink id="linkId" action="#{resultsBean.excelDownload}" style="display:none;" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
private File excelFile;

public void excelExport() {
    excelFile= new ExcelExport(results).getFile();
}

public void excelDownload() throws IOException {
    Faces.sendFile(excelFile, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation helped me understand what I was doing. For whatever reason, I could not get the jQuery `$(this).next().click();` to work and had to change it to `document.getElementById('formID:linkID').click();`.

Comment: On other note I went back to the PrimeFaces documentation and it says _"RequestContext is available in both ajax and non-ajax requests."_ I was able to close a dialog from with the RequestContext method `execute("dialog.hide();")` from the action of a `<h:commandLink>`, as a single request of course.

Comment: You're right. I fixed the oncomplete and removed the `RequestContext` statement. I missed this feature.